# Facebook iOS SDK not returning user email

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, email, sdk

I am trying to get access to some user's info, including email. For this purpose, I use the Graph API to call this method:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

It returns the user info, without the email information (the birthday is also missing). I setted all permissions and tested with more than one account (which has email and birthday as a public information), and accepted all the dialog's requests.

Here is my init:

```
if(!facebook) {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:[self _APP_KEY] andDelegate:self];
    NSArray *array =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", @"user_birthday", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil];
    [self setPermissions:array];
}

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
} 
else {
    [self getUserInfo];
}
```

The login callback:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [self getUserInfo];
}
```

The getUserInfo method:

```
- (void) getUserInfo {
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

The request callback:

```
 - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary* json = result;
        NSLog(@"-> %@", json);
    }
}
```

The result is the following:

```
-> {
    "first_name" = EDITED (my name);
    gender = male;
    hometown =     {
        id = 111072692249998;
        name = "Porto Alegre";
    };
    id = 653099452;
    languages =     (
                {
            id = 104034306299811;
            name = "Brazilian Portuguese";
        },
                {
            id = 106059522759137;
            name = English;
        }
    );
    "last_name" = EDITED (my last name);
    link = EDITED (my profile);
    locale = "en_US";
    location =     {
        id = 112047398814697;
        name = "S\U00e3o Paulo, Brazil";
    };
    name = EDITED (my name);
    timezone = "-3";
    "updated_time" = "2012-04-25T13:36:51+0000";
    verified = 1;
}
```

As you can see, there is no information about the user's email. Am I missing some step? Any ideias?

Thanks in advance

Comment: none of these answers work? or do they? You are supposed to select a correct answer here for the benefit of other users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use this, it works in my case

> facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:[self _APP_KEY] andDelegate:self];
>       [facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",nil]];

Answer (score 3):

Try this
**permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access",@"email",nil];**

Answer (score 1):

you can get the user email like this .. after the fbDidlogin fired call this method

```
- (void)fetchUserDetails {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"SELECT uid, name, pic, email FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

    [fb requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                     andParams:params
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];
}
```

and in the `request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad` you will do something like this:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{

  if([request.url rangeOfString:@"fql.query"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [result count]>0) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {

            NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]);
           }
      }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

**1) Give the permission to get the Email and the info etc...**

```
// You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_videos",@"email"]
                                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                                              completionHandler:
                 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
                 {
                     // Retrieve the app delegate
                     AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                     // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
                     [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                 }];
```

**2) to get the Email where you want...**

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error)
        {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSString *userEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
             }
            [tblSettingVw reloadData];
         }];
    }
```

**Note : User Dictionary will Return following**

```
{
    "first_name" =;
    gender =;
    id =;
    "last_name" =;
    link = "";
    locale = "";
    name = "";
    timezone = "";
    "updated_time" = "";
    verified = ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All facebook accounts which are verified through ***Phone Number*** instead of email will get `NULL` for `[user objectForKey:@"email"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can only access an user's email if you get the user's authorization for it.

The public graph does not provide this information.

You should read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: this guide is for the web api. The question is for access from ios sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission to the user for this information via:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_birthday",
                        nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
```

}

Here's all the info you need, just follow this tutorials

First, this one: [Facebook Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)

And then, this one: [Fetch user data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/user-data-ios-sdk/)